# WebStorm 11, meteor directories to exclude for faster indexing

Tags: meteor, webstorm

Using WebStorm 11.0.3 to build a Meteor app. I noticed that it takes too long to come up with some context sensitive menus with the busy colourful circle revolving.

I tried to right click on the project to see if there is "ignore folder" but did not find it.

What un necessary folders to exclude and how in order to speed up indexing on the hope that it will be faster IDE? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely exclude the .meteor/local folder. It will make indexing way more faster than what you are experiencing now.

First go to,
File -> settings -> Language & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Meteor

make sure the "Automatically exclude '.meteor/local' directory on open project" is selected.
click OK.

Then from the project tree tool bar settings menu, untick "Show Excluded Files"